# proof general cannot find library or its source file even with coq-load-path-include-current and coq-compile-before-require

Tags: emacs, coq

I'm on windows 8.1 with proof general 4.2 and emacs 24.2.1. I have set `coq-compile-before-require` and `coq-load-path-include-current` to on, but when I try to require a library whose source file is in the same folder I still get

`coq-auto-compile: no source file for c\:/Users/Greg/Documents/cpdt/src/CpdtTactics.vo`

in the minibuffer and

`Error: Cannot find library CpdtTactics in loadpath`
in the messages buffer.

Edit: OK turns out I needed to [compile the library I'm working with before it will work](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Intro.html). However I still get the coq-auto-compile message, which suggests that coq-auto-compile is not getting the path correctly.